# Slide the Android Automotive HVAC up by pressing a button

Tags: android, android-source, android-automotive

In Android Automotive, you have the HVAC FAN button in the bottom nav, and when you click on this it slides up over the content. Now I want to use my own button in my application to slide this up. When I press on the stock button, I see this in the log "Content shown: com.android.systemui.car.hvac.HvacPanelOverlayViewController"

Should I use a intent for this? There isn't really much about Android Automotive. I do know that I should maybe use some "car" import but that isn't available for regular Android Development as far as I know. Can I only use Car Properties if I build my own module project in aosp?